# Передвижение картинок мышью

Tags: delphi, изображения

Как можно передвигать `image` мышью?

Менять `Top` и `Left` с помощью передвигания мышью по нажатию на изображение.

Не нашёл похожей реализации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- в OnMouseDown запоминаешь позиции мыши относительно изображения, и запоминаешь какой-нибудь флаг, что мышь нажата
- в OnMouseWheel устанавливаешь координаты у Image с использованием относительных координат
- в OnMouseUp убираешь флаг нажатия мыши

Comment: только не OnMouseWheel, а в OnMouseMove.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov вы правы :) извиняюсь.., сказывается перемешивание языков )

Answer (score 1):

Если у изображения есть обработчики

- по нажатии мыши
- по передвижении
- по отпускании мыши

то делается очень просто

У Фленова в книжке "Библия Делфи" или в "Делфи глазами хакера" все это объяснено как делается.

Answer (score 1):

**[Drag && Drop](http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/drag_and_drop.html)**. Это механизм для перетаскивания контроллов( виджетов ) по родительской форме.

Comment: Хм, вообще **Drag && Drop** - это технология перетаскивания объект на объект, к примеру этой технологией надо пользоваться для получения изображений при перетаскивании файла изображений на форму